# Response time for more concurrent users

Tags: tomcat, concurrency, performance-testing, sticky, session-replication

I have tried searching the net, but to no avail. I have 2 questions in mind while implementing for my project..

1.To cater to more concurrent users (~300), does more Tomcat servers help in reducing the response time? 
2.The **difference in response time** for sticky session and session replication when I load test with 50 concurrent users are quite obvious. Why is the **difference in response time** between sticky session and session replication become so marginal or negligible when I load test with much more concurrent users, say, 300?

Thanks for helping me answer the queries.. Greatly appreciated!

Comment: Are you performance testing the tomcat server?

Comment: yes. it is on tomcat server. i have a total of 3 tomcat servers in the cluster.

Answer (score 1):

Latency can be caused by two parts:

- by the web servers itself or
- by backend servers (like database and/or application server).

The part of latency caused by web server can be reduced by having more web servers, however, the part of latency caused by backend server may not change or may get worse when there are more requests.

Sorry not sure I understand the second question.